# Multiline TextView and Singleline TextView in one line

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to get next result in my layout:
[left textview] [space] [right textview]
For this purpose I use it:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="left"
        android:id="@+id/left"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="right"
        android:id="@+id/right"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It's okay. But if left TextView contains a large text, the result will be next:

[left textview] (under left textview [right textview]. So left override right. But I want that left TextView doesn't override right, and when left TextView reaches right TextView the Left TextView go down into multiline. So I want to get next result:

some-text-text-left-multiline

some-text-text-left-multiline text-in-right-text-view

some-text-text-left-multiline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a linear layout (horizontal) and place textview with the same `android:layout_weight` inside to make a 50/50 split

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This expands the left until reaching the right using `android:layout_toLeftOf`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/right"
        android:text="this is a long text on the left which should be multiline and it is" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="some text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: sample]

Answer (score 0):

Do this to your layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:maxWidth="100dp"
            android:text="right" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right"
            android:text="left" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```